# Weird error when trying to write to an mmap under windows

Tags: python, windows, mmap

This simple python code:

```
import mmap  

with file("o:/temp/mmap.test", "w+b") as fp:  
    m = mmap.mmap(fp.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ|mmap.ACCESS_WRITE)  
    m.write("Hello world!")
```

Produces the following error (on the mmap.mmap(...) line):
WindowsError: [Error 1006] The volume for a file has been externally altered so that the opened file is no longer valid

Any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html#mmap.mmap):

> If length is 0, the maximum length of
>   the map is the current size of the
>   file, except that if the file is empty
>   Windows raises an exception (you
>   cannot create an empty mapping on
>   Windows).

You are opening the file with "w+" - the file is getting truncated... (size = 0)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was wandering about the weird text of the error-message, but just found out that 1006 is simply Win32's ERROR_FILE_INVALID that CreateFileMapping() produces...

Answer (score 4):

Most likely because `w+` truncates the file, and Windows gives an error when trying to create an empty mapping from that file of length 0. Use `r+` instead.

As well, you shouldn't use `access=mmap.ACCESS_READ|mmap.ACCESS_WRITE`:

```
>>> mmap.ACCESS_READ
1
>>> mmap.ACCESS_WRITE
2
>>> mmap.ACCESS_COPY
3
>>> mmap.ACCESS_READ | mmap.ACCESS_WRITE
3
```

In other words, `access=mmap.ACCESS_READ|mmap.ACCESS_WRITE` is the same as `access=mmap.ACCESS_COPY`. What you want is most likely `access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE`, and on Windows that's what you get anyway if you don't explicitly use that argument.

Try this:

```
import mmap  

with file("o:/temp/mmap.test", "r+b") as fp:  
    m = mmap.mmap(fp.fileno(), 0)  
    m.write("Hello world!")
```

( mmap docs: http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html )

Comment: Tried r+, but it gives the same error. The access= is indeed redundant, but was added just to make sure it is not a strange way of windows to say 'permission denied'

Comment: @Paul - is the file populated with data?  Length = 0 will only work with non-empty files.  If you specify a length, then the file will be extended.

Comment: All is well: the confusing part is the text of the error message (see my comment to Jeremy). I guess even an 'always look on the bright side of life' would be a better text for this error.

Comment: @Paul: especially if it made the computer whistle when thrown.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - with python 2.7.6

```
dataFile = open(dFile, mode='r+b') # failed with windows access error
dataFile = open(dFile, 'r+b')      # works
```

reading r+b, to get around \x1a SUB characters in the data, seen as end of file